# How can I modify a Windows task schedule via command line without requiring a password?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I can create a task on the Windows 10 command line using [SCHTASKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create) without needing to enter my password.  For example:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN my_test /SC MINUTE /MO 2 /TR "msg %username% Hello World"
```

*(Show Hello World message box every 2 minutes)*

But when I try to modify the task:

```
SCHTASKS /Change /TN my_test /RI 7
```

*(Change it to run every 7 minutes)*

It displays a prompt requesting a password:

`Please enter the run as password for username:`

I'd like to be able to change the task schedule via a batch script but needing to enter a password would defeat the purpose of a batch script (i.e. making things easier)

Why can I create a task with SCHTASKS without a password but modifying requires a password?
How can I modify a task schedule without requiring a password?

Comment: Answered here: [batch file - Modify Scheduled task without password - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63462003/modify-scheduled-task-without-password)

Comment: @DavidPostill From what I can tell that's a little different.  His solution involves dynamically changing the task creation so that he *doesn't* have to modify it later. While it solved his particular problem, it doesn't actually answer the question

Answer (score 4):

You can't, at least not without using an elevated Command Prompt that is
run as Administrator.

The reason is that the command `SCHTASKS /Create` has created a scheduled
task that is run under your user credentials and with your current
permissions.

However, to modify a scheduled task requires Administrator privileges.
So there you have the gotcha - you can create but not modify.

I believe that you still have the permissions to
[schtasks /delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-delete)
your scheduled task. This can be the workaround : Rather than modify,
do delete and create anew.

References :

- [schtasks change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-change)
- [schtasks create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create)

Comment: task control permissions exist and a separate from task permissions.  You can set the 'modify' permission to something else -- it doesn't have to require Administrator permission.